# How to get the :last-child element in a mixed group of selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a [bootstrap/opencart] generated sidebar navigation, by default it marks the current category AND current item/product as both 'active'

how do I get the :last-child of the tags that have been marked as 'active' [so I can give them a different presentation]

See below:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Road/Race (4)</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Off-Road (5)</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"> -> Aprilia (1)</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active"> -> BMW (0)</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"> ->Ducati (0)</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Snow (0)</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Downloads (0)</a>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
.list-group-item:last-child.active {
    background: #000 !important;
}
.list-group-item.active:last-child {
    background: #000 !important;
}
/* with and without the !important */
```

Neither selector works.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: There is no `nth-of-class` so you may have to rely on JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but perhaps something like:

```
.list-group-item.active ~ .active
```

I believe the `~` will target any `.active` that follows after the first `.active`.

Comment: Yes but it won't target **only** the last one.

Comment: Only disadvantage is if there are more than two.  A better way to explain how this will work is that all but the first `.active` element will be selected, but that may be all the OP really needs.

Comment: I suggested this as I saw it as only two elements will have the .active class. 
But yes, completely right it would select all .active elements following the first. I should have mentioned this and will try to be more thorough in future answers thank you!

Comment: As noted not a perfect solution, but considering that css *cannot* accomplish this exact task, and the question didn't give the case of having more than 2 elements of the `.active` class, this is a very clever answer!

Comment: it appears that there can only be 2 active items at the most since both bootstrap and opencart only support 2 levels of menu items.  Frankly the implementation by opencart is very poor. So in this particular situation this solution probably works.